# Align equations to replicate regression output

Tags: equations, align

I have been trying to replicate the following equation in LaTeX (from a regression output):
[image]

I have tried using `tabular` and `align` but I'm still not able to get a similar look. Specifically, the quantities in parentheses being exactly underneath the coefficients, the alignment at the decimal place, and so on. Any leads on how to achieve it?

Edit: I thought I'd include my attempt as a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{9}
    \widehat{\ti{math}4} & = 24.49 & {} - .274 & \ti{pctsgle} & {} - .422 & \ti{free} & {} - .752 & \ti{lmedinc} & {} + 9.01 & \ti{lexppp} \\
    & \phantom{{} = {}} (59.24) & (.161) & & (.071) & & (5.358) & & (4.04) \\
    n & = 299, R^2 = .472
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of the `array`. Numbers notation are slightly changed (before decimal points are always a numbers):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}  % for widehat
\newcommand{\ti}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \[\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}
      \sisetup{input-symbols = {( )}}
\begin{array}{r c
                S[table-format=2.2]  c
                S[table-format=1.3]l c
                S[table-format=1.3]l c
                S[table-format=1.3]l c
                S[table-format=1.2]l 
              }  
\widehat{\ti{math}4} 
    & = 
    & 24.49 & - & 0.274   & \ti{pctsgle} & - 
                & 0.422   & \ti{free}    & - 
                & 0.752   & \ti{lmedinc} & + 
                & 9.01    & \ti{lexppp}   \\
    &
    & (59.24) & & (0.161) & &
                & (0.071) & &
                & (5.358) & &
                & (4.04)  &               \\
n   & = &  \multicolumn{13}{l}{299,\quad R^2 = 0.472}
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd print the bottom numbers smaller, so it's unlikely that they class with the nearer ones. With `\hidewidth` we ensure that they don't take up horizontal space, but are centered under the main coefficient anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\operatorname{\mathit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\coeff}[2]{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    #1 \\ % the main number
    \scriptstyle \hidewidth(#2)\hidewidth
  \end{array}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\widehat{\tvar{math}4} 
& = \coeff{24.49}{59.24}
  - \coeff{.274}{.161} \tvar{pctsgle}
  - \coeff{.422}{.071} \tvar{free} 
  - \coeff{.752}{5.538} \tvar{lmedinc}
  + \coeff{9.01}{4.04} \tvar{lexppp}
\\
n & = 299,\quad R^2 = .472
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is `\hidewidth` defined in AMS packages? If yes, is it a new feature? I never heard about it. Nice!

Comment: @Sigur No, it's an old plain TeX macro.

Comment: Amazing. Everyday is a new day, it is time to learn more and more.